# Proper function placement

Tags: javascript

Very new to programming and have a simple question about where to put more than one function i am trying to make a tic tac toe game and the function i am trying to place is

```js
function newgame()
{
   var status = document.getElementById('status');

   xTurn = true;
   status.innerHTML = 'X\'s turn';

   for(var x = 0; x < x++)
   {
      for(var y = 0; y < y++)
      {
         document.getElementById(x + '_' + y).value = ' ';
      }
   }
}
```

***Where would it go in here** :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
var xTurn = true;

function squareclicked(square)
// squareclicked is a function that is called whenever a button is clicked.
{
 var status = document.getElementById('status');
 var value = square.value;
 if(value != 'X' && value != 'O')
 {
   if(xTurn)
   {
      square.value = 'X';
      xTurn = false;
      status.innerHTML = 'O\'s turn';
   }
   else
      {
         square.value = 'O';
         xTurn = true;
         status.innerHTML = 'X\'s turn';
      }
 }
   else
      alert('That square has already been played.');
}
</SCRIPT>

<body>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="0_0" VALUE=" " ONCLICK="squareclicked(this);">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ID="NEWGAME" VALUE="New Game" ONCLICK="newgame();">
<P ID="status">X's turn</P>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put all the functions inside the `<script>` tag.

Comment: when i put them both inside the script tag already set up the function squareclicked(square) no longer works is there a reason for this ?

Comment: Maybe you made a typo. Is there any error in the Javascript console?

Comment: You have syntax errors in your `for()` loops. It's supposed to be `for (initialization; test; update) { body }` but you're missing the `; update` part.

Comment: What is `x < x++` supposed to mean in the `for` loop? It should be `for (x = 0; x < limit; x++)` where you replace `limit` with the variable containing the number of repetitions.

Comment: ahh thank you i see that now

Comment: Why do all your buttons have the same ID? Shouldn't the X and Y run from 0 to 2?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your `for` loops in the `newgame` function. They should be:

```
for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        document.getElementById(x + '_' + y).value = ' ';
    }
}
```

If you fix this, it should work when you put them both in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: thank you for your response i tried out the new function and only the top left square is being reset do you know what would cause this ?

Comment: All your squares have the same `id="0_0"`. The next one in the same row should be `id="0_1"`, and the next row should start with `id="1_0"`, and so on.